# MongoDB field with Double data type saved as Int64 for no reason

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I have a case class with a field that is Double:

```
case class MyModel(amount: Option[Double])
```

I work with mongodb4 and use reactivemongo 0.19.0 with play framework 2.7.2 with Scala 2.12.8

from some reason, randomly, when I insert MyModel elements to the db amount field saved as int64 instead of Double, which is very weird cause most of the time not, just randomly.

its not a decimal point thing cause I saw other documents that this field don't have decimal point and it still saved as Double correctly.

what are your thoughts?

this is the insertion function:

```
  def insertOneWithoutEvent(doc: Doc): Future[Doc] = {
    doc.createdAt = Some(InstantNow)
    doc.updatedAt = doc.createdAt
    (for {
      insertedDoc <- collection.insert.one(doc)
        .map({
          case DefaultWriteResult(true, 1, _, _, _, _) => doc
          case dwr => throw new RuntimeException(s"$LogName was not inserted, something went wrong: $dwr")
        })
    } yield insertedDoc)
      .recover({
        case WriteResult.Code(DuplicateCode) => throw DuplicateKeyException(doc.uniqueIndexToString)
      })
  }
```

Comment: Could you show how you are inserting and retrieving that data? Is it possible to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @GastónSchabas added the insertion method, the Doc type is just a general type and you can call it and pass it whatever type you have, in my case it would be MyModel.
the fetch is not important here cause the problem is it get saved in the wrong type...instead of double its int64

Comment: The provided code is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The collection is not defined and also you are not showing how you are serializing your objects. If the value you are trying to save is not the expected one, I would guess the problem is how you are serializing the object. Please edit your post and show something also how you are validating (steps followed such as which command you executed) to validate that the type of the value is not the correct one